# How to reset the size of the Stack Trace Window?

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, message-coding

Normally the size of the Stack Trace window can easily be changed using the `ResizeArea` element in the lower right corner. However, if one makes this window too small, this element disappears.

[image: Example]

As Mathematica remembers the last size used for this window, also all future Stack Trace windows are too small now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivateFrontEndOptions, "InterfaceSettings", 
   "MessageStack", "ImageSize"}] = Inherited
```

Resets the the size of the Stack Trace window to its default.

Alternatively, one can put `InterfaceSettings` into the Lookup field of the Option Inspector and change the option setting back to `"MessageStack" -> {"ImageSize" -> {600, 300}}`.

Comment: neat find, and potential disaster averted. +1